# How can I make this operator overload work?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, operator-overloading, typename

I am using C++, I am relatively new to the language. Before even compiling, VSCode highlights that my transform call is overloaded. I suspect that this is because of the unclear typename, but this is needed to overload a vector, so how can I fix this?

```
template <typename U>
vector<U> operator+(const vector<U>& v1, const vector<U>& v2) {
    vector<U> result(v1.size());
    transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), result.begin(), [] (U& a, U& b) {return a + b; });
    return result;
}
```

I have tried changing from U to T, or using vector double throughout, but nothing fixed the issue.

Comment: Typo. `v1` and `v2` are `const vector<U> &`. You pass `U &a, U& b` into the lambda; however, these need to be `const`. Change your lambda's parameters to `const U& a, const U& b`

Comment: Voted to reopen. Close voters: how did you determine that the person who wrote the question knew how to do it, but mis-typed the code? Seems much more likely that this comes from not understanding how `const` propagates; it's not self-evident here. It's not a typo just because it would be one if **you** typed it.

Comment: On a side note: this code will fail if `v2.size()` is less than `v1.size()`. If you want to add different-sized vectors, you can do something like this: `template <typename U> vector<U> operator+(const vector<U>& v1, const vector<U>& v2) { auto min_size = min(v1.size(), v2.size()); vector<U> result(max(v1.size(), v2.size())); transform(v1.begin(), v1.begin()+min_size, v2.begin(), result.begin(), [](const U& a, const U& b){ return a + b; }); const auto &the_rest = (v1.size() < v2.size()) ? v2 : v1; copy(the_rest.begin()+min_size, the_rest.end(), result.begin()+min_size); return result; }`

Comment: Post the error you're getting and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise the program(as given) could be IFNDR(ill formed no diagnostic required).